# Accuracy is high everytime but the resulting prediction is wrong

Tags: python, machine-learning, prediction, predict

I am trying to predict the crop name by entering the temperature, soil humidity, pH and average rainfall. 
And the accuracy percentage is always high i.e it ranges from 88% to 94% everytime. But the final result after prediction is always wrong.
This is the code:

```
#importing the required libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#Reading the csv file
data=pd.read_csv('cpdata.csv')

#Creating dummy variable for target i.e label
label= pd.get_dummies(data.label).iloc[: , 1:]
data= pd.concat([data,label],axis=1)
data.drop('label', axis=1,inplace=True)
print('The data present in one row of the dataset is')
print(data.head(1))
train=data.iloc[:, 0:4].values
test=data.iloc[: ,4:].values

#Dividing the data into training and test set
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(train,test,test_size=0.3)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

#Importing Decision Tree classifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
clf=DecisionTreeRegressor()

#Fitting the classifier into training set
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
pred=clf.predict(X_test)


from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
# Finding the accuracy of the model
a=accuracy_score(y_test,pred)
print("The accuracy of this model is: ", a*100)

ah=89.41
atemp=26.98
shum=28
pH=6.26
rain=58.54


l=[]
l.append(atemp)
l.append(ah)
l.append(pH)
l.append(rain)
predictcrop=[l]

# Putting the names of crop in a single list
crops=['rice','wheat','mungbean','Tea','millet','maize','lentil','jute','cofee','cotton','ground nut','peas','rubber','sugarcane','tobacco','kidney beans','moth beans','coconut','blackgram','adzuki beans','pigeon peas','chick peas','banana','grapes','apple','mango','muskmelon','orange','papaya','pomegranate','watermelon']
cr='rice'

#Predicting the crop
predictions = clf.predict(predictcrop)
count=0
for i in range(0,31):
    if(predictions[0][i]==1):
        c=crops[i]
        count=count+1
        break;
    i=i+1
if(count==0):
    print('The predicted crop is %s'%cr)
else:
    print('The predicted crop is %s'%c)
```

The output that I am getting is-

```
The accuracy of this model is:  90.43010752688173
The predicted crop is apple
```

Even though I enter the exact values for any other crop, I get apple or mango every time.

Kindly help.

Comment: How many examples are there in your dataset? I am a bit confused how you split your dataset into training and testset, this should normally look like that: `train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y = train_test_split(data,labels,test_size=0.3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the scaler also to your new data for prediction. I cannot test it without your data but it should look somehow like:

```
datascaled = sc.transform(predictcrop)
predictions = clf.predict(datascaled)
```

In order to apply the scaler also to new data later, you need to save it:

```
from sklearn.externals.joblib import dump, load
dump(sc, 'scaler.bin', compress=True)
```

and later:

```
sc=load('scaler.bin')
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! You were a great a help!!